# Error using WITH clause and UPDATE in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

i tried to run this query:

````
WITH updateables AS (
    SELECT id_product, quantity
    FROM products_order
    WHERE id_order = 1239 AND state = 10
)
UPDATE product
SET product.stock = updateables.quantity
WHERE product.id_product = updateables.id_product```
````

But this trows:

````
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'updateables.id_product' in 'where clause```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defining a CTE using the `WITH` clause does not implicitly join that CTE to other tables in your query.

You would need to use a JOIN in your query to the CTE:

```
WITH updateables AS (
    SELECT id_product, quantity
    FROM products_order
    WHERE id_order = 1239 AND state = 10
)
UPDATE product JOIN updateables ON product.id_product = updateables.id_product
SET product.stock = updateables.quantity;
```

Comment: thank you very much!